# SDL_BlitSurface argument pointer of an 2D array of structure containing a SDL_Rect

Tags: c, pointers, sdl, multidimensional-array

I am in the beginning of a game and I'm stuck in the `Blit_Surface` step. My CodeBlocks compiler says invalid type argument of `->` (have `BrickStruct`)" at compiling. It seems like it wants a pointer to my 2D array, however I had in mind that a 2D array was a pointer toward the 1st member of the 1st array, in which each member is a pointer toward the 1st member of the 2nd array ? In this case it looks like there's no need for a pointer in argument, isn't it ? I can't find where the type problem is.

```
void Display(BrickStruct Bricks[12][10],SDL_Surface *ecran)
{
    int i=0,j=0;

    for(j=0;j<10;j++)
    {
        if( (j+1)%2==0 )  // If we are on even lines, display only 11 bricks
        {
            for(i=0;i<11;i++)
            {
                Bricks[i][j].Brick_Surface = IMG_Load("BrickTest1.png");
                SDL_BlitSurface(Bricks[i][j].Brick_Surface, NULL, ecran, Bricks[i][j]->Brick_Coordinates);
            }
        }
        else   // If we are on odd lines, display the 12 bricks
        {
            for(i=0;i<12;i++)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Structure looks like this:

```
typedef struct BrickStruct
{
    int type;
    SDL_Rect Brick_Coordinates;   
    SDL_Surface *Brick_Surface;  
}BrickStruct;
```

In my main, my code is like this:

```
SDL_Surface *ecran = NULL; 

BrickStruct Bricks[12][10];  // I create my 2D array of struct named Bricks

Display(Bricks,&ecran);
```

Can somebody please have the kindness to indicate me where is located my problem ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiler is right, of course.

```
SDL_BlitSurface(Bricks[i][j].Brick_Surface, NULL, ecran, &Bricks[i][j].Brick_Coordinates);
```

But reloading image on each draw 120 times? Really? Even worse, not destroying it.

Comment: Don't worry, it will crash even before that (see that NULL ecran? ;))

Comment: This code is for a Block Breaker game (Breakout type). the 120 images are my bricks. For the moment they all have the same skin, just for testing.

Comment: @MichałGóral sure, noticed that, but no question was asked about it :-)

Comment: I haven't posted all my code. There's another function Initializing SDL and the ecran Surface with SDL_SetVideoMode

Comment: In the end that's not very helpful. It's the first time I'm using SDL on my own after the 1 week lesson we get. And I'm getting a little disturbed in using pointer of 1D array/2D array with structures of structures combined together instead of "simple" pointers of variables

Comment: @paolovador your '2D' arrays are just ordinary 1D arrays - it only affects how index is calculated (in other words, it is not array of pointers to arrays, it have plain memory layout). In my view, it is bad to use multi-dimentional arrays - 1D with manual control over index is better. But anyway - my answer corrects obvious semantic error which compiler reported. If you still have problem with that - you probably should update your question with additional information.

Comment: I still haven't figured out which type I need to pass my Struct of coordinate with to my function SDL_BlitSurface. Sorry, I'm sure you thought of your answer as an explicit one but I still don't get it.
I tried with `Bricks[i][j].Brick_Coordinates` or even with `(*Bricks)[i][j]->Brick_Coordinates`, and more but no success

Comment: @Keltar Sorry, I just noticed the changes you made to my 4th argument. My eyes were surely tired. Thanks you very much that worked.